# How come my uitextfield(s) keeps being disabled after model?

Tags: objective-c

I made an app for my wife to track inventory.  it has a couple of view controllers to enter a new item, display all items, search items, and display selected item. After switching through each view a couple of times (no particular order) all of the textfields become disabled (you cannot select them to change the value) across ALL of the view controllers.  The buttons still work however. I have it setup so that when the user enters info into a particular cell, it saves it into memory so that if they switch views and then come back, the cells will get the data in the viewdidload method. Please Help!

*edit - I am using storyboard with a bunch of segues (i'm new to programming and self taught, so idk if this is the right way or not)... here is a pic of my storyboard

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUytc.png

Comment: You need to show how you are cycling through the views. Are you using a storyboard and segues? If so, it would be useful if you could post a picture of your storyboard somewhere.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time posting on here... I am cycling through my views with segues on the storyboard...here is a pic of my storyboard.. thanks for your help... http://i.imgur.com/aT3PR0i.png

Comment: You're a good husband ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with a look at your storyboard, I think I see your problem. If your storyboard looks like somebody spilled spaghetti on it, it's not designed correctly. Specifically, it looks like you're going "backwards" (to controllers you've already been to) using segues -- that's not good. SEGUES ALWAYS INSTANTIATE NEW CONTROLLERS! So, if you go around in a circle a few times, you're adding more and more controllers to your project. To go backwards using segues, you need to use an unwind segue -- it's the only one that is an exception to the rule that segues always instantiate new controllers. The other ways to go backwards, without segues, are popping with navigation controllers, and dismissing modal controllers.

I can't really diagnose your immediate problem without a lot more information, but redesigning the storyboard using unwind segues would probably fix your problem.

Comment: awesome... i had no idea... but it all makes sense now... i will lookup how to fix it... fix it... and post back on here... thank you so much!

Comment: it fixed it!... i had no idea how to use the segues on storyboard... very easy to do now and makes so much more sense... thank you for your help